# Não está parando submit com e.preventDefault();

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Eu tenho esta função abaixo, porém ela não esta parando no `e.preventDefault();`, ela executa e realiza o `submit` da página.
Segue como estou fazendo:

```
 $('#ClienteEditar').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = "/Cliente/VerificaInscricao1";
    var Insc = $("#InscricaoEstadual").val();
    var Tipo = $("#TipoPessoa").val();
    var Id = $("#Id").val();
    var Isento = $("#InscricaoIsento").prop('checked');
    var form = this,
        $form = $(form); // Salvamos o formulário atual em uma variável
    var verificaform = 1;

    $.each($('input[data-required="true"]'), function () {
        if (!this.value || this.value == '') {
            e.preventDefault();
            verificaform = 1;
            $(this).css('border', 'red 1px solid');
            var id = $($(this).parents('.tab-pane')[0]).attr('id');
            $('[href="#' + id + '"]').trigger('click');
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $(this).css('border', '#CCCCCC 1px solid');
        }

        if ($('#ClienteEditar').valid()) {
            verificaform = 0;
        }
    });
    if (verificaform == 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { insc: Insc, id: Id, isento: Isento, tipo: Tipo },
            datatype: "json",
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.resultado == true) {

                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("#messageI").html(data.mensagem);
                    if (data.mensagem != 'O campo Inscrição é obrigatório.') {
                        $("#InscricaoEstadual").val('');
                        $("#InscricaoEstadual").focus();
                    }
                    $("#InscricaoEstadual").css('border', 'red 1px solid');
                    var id = $($("#InscricaoEstadual").parents('.tab-pane')[0]).attr('id');
                    $('[href="#' + id + '"]').trigger('click');
                    return false;
                }

            }
        });
        var url1 = "/Cliente/VerificaDocumento1";
        var Documento = $("#Documento").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: url1,
            data: { documento: Documento, id: Id, tipo: Tipo },
            datatype: "json",
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.resultado == true) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("#message").html(data.mensagem);
                    $("#Documento").css('border', 'red 1px solid');
                    var id = $($("#Documento").parents('.tab-pane')[0]).attr('id');
                    $('[href="#' + id + '"]').trigger('click');
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    if ($('#ClienteEditar').valid()) {
                        $form.off('submit').submit();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Como posso corrigir, preciso que ele realize o submit apenas se entrar no `else`.

Comment: Tente utilizar o a função `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`

Comment: @sant0will não resolveu, ocorre o mesmo problema.

Comment: Já tentou colocar um `return false;` no fim da função?

Comment: Nas duas partes que eu preciso que pare, além do `e.preventDefault();`, tem o `return false;` como pode ver.

Comment: Você colocou `return false;` dentro dos callbacks dos ajax e dentro do `.each`, a função que é a handler do evento submit não retorna `false` nunca.

Comment: @fernandosavio porém eu preciso que ele execute cada função de uma vez, e dependendo do retorno do ajax, ele pare a função, ou continue. E dentro do `.each` o `return false;` funciona.

Comment: OK, para cancelar a submissão o handler precisar retornar `false` e a sua função não retorna nada, por isso não cancela o envio. Como você está usando AJAX síncrono você poderia ter uma variável guardando o retorno, que seria `false` caso o evento devesse ser cancelado. Mas o ponto é, sua função não retorna nada, por isso o cancelamento não é realizado.

Comment: Correção: não posso ter certeza se é por isso que o cancelamento não é efetuado. Mas acredito que sim

Comment: Aqui `$form.off('submit').submit();` vc está cancelando o evento submit e submetendo o formulário sem o evento ao mesmo tempo. Deixe apenas `$form.off('submit');`, porém o botão submit ainda irá funcionar sem o evento. Tem que ver o que vc quer fazer ao entrar nesse if.

Comment: @fernandosavio fiz isso,coloquei a variável e fiz um if, com `return false;` e resolveu o problema.